# How to get post data from facebook page using python?

Tags: python, facebook

I try to get post data from facebook page using Facebook Graph API like this.

[image]

The output not show anything. So I try to use facebook-scraper like [this tutorial.](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/facebook-post-scraping-and-text-analytics-9eea10563a3a)

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
import pandas as pd

post_df_full = pd.DataFrame(columns = [])

for post in get_posts('bbcnews', extra_info=True, pages=5, options={"comments": True}):
    post_entry = post
    print(post_entry)
    fb_post_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(post_entry, orient='index')
    fb_post_df = fb_post_df.transpose()
    post_df_full = post_df_full.append(fb_post_df)
```

I use this code to print post_entry which is the post from page but it not show anything. How to fix it?

Comment: You can not get data from pages via API any more, just because they happen to be "public". Your app would need the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/) feature - but allowed uses cases for that are limited to providing "competitive benchmark analysis".

Answer (score 0):

Since you already converted the json to dataframe, you just simply call the dataframe to get the result:

```
post_df_full.head()
```